# telerik radgrid with external filter control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik

I want to have the filter controls of a radgrid sit outside the radgrid. can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, like on [this sample](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridcomboajax/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid). With multiple outside filters you have to apply several control parameters for your data source controls or build the filter expression of the grid by hand.

Comment: not using a datasource control i'm binding a datatable to the radgrid in code behind. any examples how to do that sample in code behind using a datatable

Comment: Here is a quick one: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/filtertemplate/defaultcs.aspx. See the RefreshCombos method and how the WHERE clauses are defined - should work the same way with DataTables.